# Локализация рублей в Swift 5.3, XCode 13 — RUB вместо ₽

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, ipad

Делаю универсальное приложение для iOS, iPadOS, macOS. Приложение работает с кодами валют, приходящими из JSON API: RUB, USD, EUR и другие. Для отображения в приложении я конвертирую их в символы: ₽, $, €. Вроде задача элементарная и частично у меня получилось.

Воспользовался классом Locale.

Теперь внимание: все три символа прекрасно конвертируются в iOS Simulator, но ₽ остаётся как RUB на реальных устройствах — iOS, iPadOS, macOS.

```
import UIKit

func getSymbol(code: String) -> String? {
    let result = Locale
        .availableIdentifiers
        .map { Locale(identifier: $0) }
        .first { $0.currencyCode == code }

    return result?.currencySymbol
}

print(getSymbol(code: "RUB")!) // ₽
```

Этот пример для Playground работает и заменяет RUB на ₽.
Этот же код не работает на реальном iPhone, iPad, macOS.

В чём может быть проблема? Выглядит как баг библиотеки локализации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не баг, а фича. Если выполнить следующий код

```
for identifier in Locale.availableIdentifiers {
    let locale = Locale(identifier: identifier)
            
    if locale.currencyCode == code {
        print("\(identifier)\t\(locale.currencyCode)\t\(locale.currencySymbol)")
    }

}
```

то мы получим

```
ba_RU   Optional("RUB") Optional("RUB")
ru_RU   Optional("RUB") Optional("₽")
cv_RU   Optional("RUB") Optional("RUB")
sah_RU  Optional("RUB") Optional("₽")
ce_RU   Optional("RUB") Optional("₽")
myv_RU  Optional("RUB") Optional("RUB")
tt_RU   Optional("RUB") Optional("₽")
os_RU   Optional("RUB") Optional("₽")
en_RU   Optional("RUB") Optional("RUB")
```

То бишь для разных локалей символ разный, и в вашем коде он видимо берется для `ba_RU`.

**Вариант 1** - грязный фикс - это исправить ваш код таким образом, но не факт, что он будет работать для других валют

```
let result = Locale
            .availableIdentifiers
            .map { Locale(identifier: $0) }
            .first { $0.currencyCode == code && $0.currencySymbol != code } // <--
```

**Вариант 2** - использовать напрямую локаль (например текущую локаль юзера, если мы делаем вывод в интерфейс), а не код валюты, так как символ валюты как мы видим для разных локалей разный, и здесь вопрос, для какой локали вы хотите этот символ получить

```
func getSymbol(locale: Locale) -> String? {
    locale.currencySymbol
}
```

Comment: спасибо за прекрасный развёрнутый ответ! вот что я выяснил с помощью ваших примеров:

1) локаль на устройствах выставлена как en

Comment: 2) я вывел список доступных локалей:

ba_RU RUB ₽
ru_RU RUB ₽
cv_RU RUB ₽
sah_RU RUB ₽
ce_RU RUB ₽
myv_RU RUB ₽
tt_RU RUB ₽
os_RU RUB ₽
en_RU RUB RUB

как видно, для моей локали действительно символ и есть RUB.
и теперь вопрос ещё усложнился: а как сделать локаль русской, если все три устройства у меня и так русифицированы, но показывают RUB?

а вот Симулятор английский, показывает локаль en, но при этом показывает знак рубля!

Comment: @foxwwweb проверьте в настройках устройств не только язык, но и регион, при верной установке можно использовать `Locale.autoupdatingCurrent` для получения текущей локали, правда для этого в приложении в настройках проекта еще нужно добавить соответствующую локализацию (например Russian для получения результатов на русском)

Answer (score 0):

Решения пробовал разные, решил добавить костыль, что если RUB — то ₽:

```
let result = Locale
    .availableIdentifiers
    .map { Locale(identifier: $0) }
    .first { $0.currencyCode == currency.rawValue }
        
return result?.currencySymbol == "RUB" ? "₽" : String(result?.currencySymbol ?? "?")
```